# Not able to select value in CJuiAutoComplete in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, yii

I have an auto complete widget in my form.

```
  <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete',array(
        'name' => 'doctor',
        'id'  => 'auto',
        'source' =>  MyController::createUrl('autocompleteTest',array('id'=>uniqid())),
        'value'=>$dname,
        'options' => array(
        'showAnim' => 'fold',
        'autoFill'=>true,
        'minLength'=>'0',

        'select'=>"js:function(event, ui) {
                   $('#Model_name').val(ui.item.id).change();
                   $('#Model_department').val(ui.item.name).change();


                                    }"
        ),
        'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'id'=>'auto',

  ),


  ));?>


     <script>
    $("#auto").bind('focus', function()
    {
    document.getElementById("auto").value="";
    $(this).autocomplete("search");
    }
    );
     </script>
```

The above code works in firefox and chrome, but not in IE. In IE, i got an error like "Unexpected call to method or proprty access". The following code is the problem.

```
append: function() {
    return this.domManip(arguments, true, function( elem ) {
        if ( this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11 ) {
            this.appendChild( elem );
        }
    });
},
```

I know that this is a well known problem in IE. But how to fix this in my code?

Comment: I too hate it! But can't miss that 9% hu still use it for browsing! :-D

Comment: My boss also uses IE though. I hate him too :)

Comment: No way to fix it??Common guys..suggest me a fix!!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line at the head of your script

```
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=Edge'>
```

Comment: It is there.'<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">'.

Comment: Sorry.There was a mistake in my qstn.Please see the updated qstn.